# unobstrusive javascript validation without strongly typed html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

Can we generate the unobtrusive javascript validation attributes
(the data annotation from model, such as

```
data-val-number="The field WI % must be a number."
data-val-range="The field WI % must be between 0 and 100."
```

)

Without using the strongly typed HTML Helpers ( such as TextBoxFor / EditorFor etc ) just using the Html.TextBox() etc